# How to install ecs_locl.h and ech_locl.h headres with OpenSSL build?

Tags: openssl, openssl-engine

Two headers in subject that define "struct ecdsa_method" and "struct ecdh_method" are not copied to the target directory when you build and install openssl using traditional commands:

```
config
make install
```

However, types that use these structures, such as ECDSA_METHOD and ECDH_METHOD are defined in ecdsa.h, which is copied to the target directory. It leads to a confusing "incomplete variable definition" error when you try to compile code that uses any of the types above. You'll inevitably run into this error if try to build an openssl engine with ECDSA and ECDH methods implemented.

I've checked a Makefile generated by config and found out that there is a variable called EXHEADERS that is used in the install process, but I didn't find a regular way of populating it through 'config' options.

The workaround is to manually copy the missing headers from a source tree to the target driectory, but I don't like this "solution".

Comment: There is no real "solution" to this, it is a shortcoming of OpenSSL at the moment. You could just copy the header files to your local source directory and use them from there. You have to keep them in synch if they change with different OpenSSL versions. Not really elegant.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I did, but I don't like it. Probably I should ask openssl community then. Thanks.

Comment: I already did that, see [here](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2015-June/001620.html). No real answer though. Another question can be found [here](https://mta.openssl.org/pipermail/openssl-users/2015-June/001496.html), about the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks like we're on our own. I was laughing when reading the only answer to your qs: "Unfortunately, someone thinks that OpenSSL should be made
as useless as possible, strangely, this all began shortly
after the heartbleed backdoor was closed". So true, but since penetration to other open source tools is big you just can't ignore openssl ... yet.

Comment: ...yet? What do you mean, do you have any big plans? ;-)

Comment: I could see other SSL implementations and I hope that they will eventually replace openssl.